# Did I use gradient descent correctly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gradient-descent

In an attempt to learn Gradient Descent. I've created my own dataset which is a the total bill of a meal with tips. As I created the perfect data so I make every meal with 10% tip.

I purposely create a very large dataset as I heard that Gradient Descent is faster than normal Linear Regression.

So here's my code.

```
x = np.random.randint(100, size=100000000)
y = x * 0.10

x = x[:,None]

now = time.time()

clf = SGDRegressor()
clf.fit(x, y)

later = time.time()
difference = int(later - now) 
print("Time spent for SGDRegressor is %d seconds" % difference)    
print("slope is %f and intercept is %s" % (clf.coef_, clf.intercept_[0]))
```

However, the result is way off that my Linear Regression method. I'm not sure if I did something wrong. I noticed about feature selection in Machine Learning Coursera. I'm not sure if my example has problems with feature selection?

Here's the code I use for normal equation

```
now = time.time()

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x=large_total_bills, y=large_tips)
predicted_tips = (slope * 700) + intercept

later = time.time()
difference = int(later - now) 
print('The customer will leave the tip of $%f' % predicted_tips)
print('The time spent is %f seconds' % difference)
```

Comment: Can you post the code for what your Linear Regression method is? Are you inverting a large matrix (i.e. solving the normal equations)?

Comment: I've updated my question to include normal equation.

Comment: Did you mean to say the total bill of a "meal" with tips instead of "mean?"

Comment: Sorry you're right it's meal not mean i will update the question

Comment: I've taken your code, reduced the number of samples to a more manageble 100,000 and ran it. (I've added `print(clf.score(x[-100:].reshape(-1,1), y[-100:]))` and excluded a 100 samples from training) This worked great. However when playing with `randint` and setting the first argument to, say, 120 I got of the scale results. Not sure what's going on.